# IE9 Javascript: wait until selection end

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-9

I have this script that captures the selected text, I would like to only do something when the selecting of text ends, not while the selection is in progress, the browser is IE9 only.

The text can also be selected by double-clicking on a word in which case the function also should do something once, when I use `onMouseUp` this is twice.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectedText(){
      var doc = document.selection;
      if(doc && doc.createRange().text.length != 0){
        log.innerHTML = doc.createRange().text;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onselect="selectedText();">
  <span id=sp>this is the text from where you can select one or more words</span>
  <div id=log style="background-color=yellow;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out, this is for future reference

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        count = 0;
        function selectedText(){
          var doc = document.selection;
          if(doc && doc.createRange().text.length != 0){
            count++;
            log.innerHTML = "count: "+count+" "+doc.createRange().text;
          }
        }

        function AddEventHandler () {
          var sp = document.getElementById ("sp");
          if (sp.addEventListener) {   // all browsers except IE before version 9
            sp.addEventListener ("click", selectedText, false);
          } 
          else {
            if (sp.attachEvent) {    // IE before version 9
              sp.attachEvent ('onmouseup', selectedText);
            }
          }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload=AddEventHandler()>
    <span id=sp>this is the text from where you can select one or more words</span>
    <div id=log style="background-color=yellow;"></div>
</body>
```

or this shorter version

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    count = 0;
    document.onselectionchange = function() { 
      count++;
      var sel = window.getSelection(); 
      if (sel.rangeCount > 0) { 
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
        document.getElementById("log") = count+":"+range.toString(); 
      } 
    }; 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id=sp>this is the text from where you can select one or more words</span>
  <div id=log style="background-color=yellow;"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE supports a `selectionchange` event on `Document` objects that is more useful than the `select` event but still won't do exactly as you ask, because the process of double clicking may change the selection more than once and hence fire more than one `selectionchange` event.

Here's an example using that event that will work in IE at least as far back as IE 6:

```
document.onselectionchange = function() {
    var sel = document.selection;
    if (sel.type == "Text") {
        var range = sel.createRange();
        document.getElementById("log") = range.text;
    }
};
```

If you don't care about earlier versions of IE, you can use IE 9's support for the standard DOM range and selection APIs and then this code will also work in WebKit:

```
document.onselectionchange = function() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        document.getElementById("log") = range.toString();
    }
};
```

Comment: tried the second in IE9 but when i drag to select i can only select 1 or 2 characters, then it stops